# Laravel Join only select one match

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm currently trying to get some info from "organizations" table, and then and need some values about this organization from the "organization_stocks" table, but I only want the newest match, and only that one (So 1 match per organization)

This is my current code, but as you can see, it returns multible rows belonging to the same organization.

```
        $data = DB::table('organization_stocks')
            ->rightJoin('organizations', 'organizations.id', '=', 'organization_stocks.organization_id')
            ->select('organizations.id', 'organizations.name', 'organization_stocks.value', 'organization_stocks.change', 'organization_stocks.state')
            ->where('active', '=', '1')
            ->orderBy('organization_stocks.timestamp', 'desc')
            ->take(5)
            ->get();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the newest match you just use `->first();` instead of `->get()` and because you are already ordering them you should be fine. I'm assuming that `timestamp` is your column equivalent to `created_at`?

You can see more info here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent

The example given in the documentation: `$comments = Post::find(1)->comments()->where('title', '=', 'foo')->first();`

Edit: You might also be able to achieve what you want without needing all the joins by simply setting up your model relationships correctly, if you need to read further this article could help: http://culttt.com/2013/06/10/laravel-4-eloquent-model-relationships/

Comment: But will I also be able to get 5 rows by using first()? (as you can see, im taking 5 entries ->take(5))

Comment: I'm confused, because you've mentioned: "but I only want the newest match, and only that one". Do you want only one or 5? As I said, you would probably be better off configuring the relationships properly.

Comment: What I need is 5 rows from the "organizations" table, And I need some info about these organizations, from the "organization_stocks" table, however there is multible onces where 'organizations.id', '=', 'organization_stocks.organization_id'. And each time it gets one where 'organizations.id', '=', 'organization_stocks.organization_id' it should not get any more rows from "organization_stocks" related to that "organisation.id", but move on to the next entry it needs info about.